# scala Array[Byte] diff

Tags: arrays, string, scala

I am using diff method to compare two String's byte arrays but giving unexpected (or is it the expected behavior?) results.

`diff()` returns `true` for `(subString diff originalString)`, but returns `false` for `(originalString diff subString)`. Would be great if any one can explain this. Code sample & output are given below.

**Code snippet**

```
val subString : Array[Byte] = "cde".getBytes("UTF-8")
val originalString : Array[Byte] = "abcdefg".getBytes("UTF-8")

println(s"compare subString with originalString - ${((subString diff originalString).isEmpty).toString}")
println(s"compare originalString with subString - ${((originalString diff subString).isEmpty).toString}")
```

**Output**

```
compare subString with originalString - true

compare originalString with subString - false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diff` is not *compare*; it is like set difference, "what are the characters that are in the first string but not in the second one?"

```
"abcd" diff "a" = "bcd"
"a" diff "abcd" = ""
```

so these are *almost* equivalent:

```
"abc".toSet diff "cb".toSet = Set(a)
"abc" diff "cb" = "a"
```